# JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:0

Tags: three.js

While i'm trying to add an object in my ThreeJs code, i had this error loading the object and i didn't understand why or how to fix it.

The error :

```
THREE:ObjectLoader: Can't parse cartoonobj/boy.json. JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:0
```

My code where the error found:

```
             var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
             loader.load("cartoonobj/boy.json",function ( obj ) {
             obj.scale.x = obj.scale.y=obj.scale.z =50.0;
             obj.position.y=-350.0;
             obj.position.x=0.0;
             obj.position.z=-1500.0;
             scene.add( obj );
         });
```

Comment: the error says that `boy.json` could not be parsed. maybe you can post that file.

Comment: Please paste the boy.json

Comment: Is the file also in the right path? Can you try ./cartoonobj/boy.json

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/rej2cyiyye4ypbf/boy.rar/file

Comment: Your shared file seems to be empty.

Comment: I don't think so, but when I tried to use .dae the error has been removed